# Делегаты и элементы формы в VS2015. Теория

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, делегаты

Добрый день. Читаю книгу Пола Дейтела - Полное руководство по C# за 2006 год. Дошёл до раздела с делегатами. После прочтения главы, мне на минутку показалось, что я понял тему, поскольку смог реализовать простой код, который считает до 10:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace consoledemo
{
    public delegate void TopMessage(string message); //объявление делегата. Делегат - это тип данных по ссылке.

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TopMessage method = Show; // Тут объявлена ссылка на метод с совпадающей сигнатурой (Show)

            ShowMessage(10, method); //method передаётся сюда вторым параметром
        }

        static void ShowMessage(int second, TopMessage method)//TopMessage передаёт ссылку на метод совпадающей сигнатурой. method является переменной, в которой хранится ссылка
        {
            for (int i  = 0; i < second; i++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                method(string.Format("How long before closing the console: " + i)); //method транслирует свои сообщения в другой метод
            }
        }

        static void Show (string message) // данный метод имеет сигнатуру точно такую же, как объявлено в делегате (TopMessage)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(message);
        }

    }
}
```

Но поскольку Дейтел в своей книге большую часть примеров демонстрирует в консоли, я решил немного усложнить себе задачу. Я добавляю кнопку и метку. По нажатию на кнопку, в метку должно было транслироваться сообщение `How long before closing the console:` после чего, метка должна была становится невидимой. Если проблема с исчезновением метки вполне решаема, то реализация отображения сообщения является для меня проблемой. Если в метод `Main` я добавлю: `label1.Text = method.ToString();` то получу заморозку окна на 10 секунд (поскольку не вывел это дело в отдельный поток), а по завершению, метка будет отображать текст `Win32Demo.TopMessage`. Максимум, что я смог сделать, это подключить класс `MessageBox.Show`.
Как мне заставить метод `Show` транслировать свои сообщения в свойства `Button1.text` , `Label1.text` и так далее.
Спасибо за ответы, Любитель.

Comment: Тут не в делагатах дело...

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` в UI пользоваться нельзя, это одно из самых больших отличий.

Comment: Книга 2006 года - очень старая книга. Уже 10 лет прошло, за это время в C# много чего появилось. Найдите более свежий вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В label1 отображается неправильный текст, потому что в ее свойство Text присваивается результат вызова метода ToString у объекта, являющегося делегатом метода. А на самом деле, в переменную текст следует поместить результат выполнения делегата: `label1.Text = method();`

Для этого необходимо изменить и сам делегат, и реализацию соответствующего метода.

```
public delegate string TopMessage(int seconds);

static string Show (int seconds)
{
  return string.Format("How long before closing the console: " + seconds);
}
```

Для того, чтобы не замораживать UI во время ожидания одной секунды, следует вместо метода ThreadSleep использовать компонент [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).